# Cassandra - Nodejs - Issue while retrieving list type values

Tags: node.js, cassandra

for example below is the table structure.

---

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
 name text,
 id text PRIMARY KEY,
 details list<text>
)
```

---

Assume
details[0]-> contact number,
details[1]-> Address

I want to write a query to extract contact number from this table.

Comment: Please tag it with only one database type for which you require the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you should not store arrays of data. The best and simplest way will be to refactor your database to something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name(
 name text,
 id text PRIMARY KEY,
 contact number NOT NULL, 
 address text NOT NULL,
)
```

Then you could do `SELECT contact FROM table_name`. If the same address can be reused between multiple entities then you may think about adding one more table `Addresses` and then using foreign keys to relate this data.

Comment: thank you, but the requirement is to store details in a list type. could you please help me with that

Comment: Try `SELECT details[1] AS contact, details[2] AS address FROM table_name;`